# Diamond collector getting terminated

Tags: linux, ubuntu

We are running a diamond collector to collect system metrics and show it on a graph. However, when I try to run the service using `service diamond start`, it will start but immediately get terminated. I tried to find the log. Syslog says

> `init: diamond main process (32501) terminated with status 1`

The following are the `/etc/log/diamond/diamond.log`

```
[2016-09-11 08:07:25,649] [MainThread] Can not find collector AppMetricCollector
[2016-09-11 08:07:29,713] [MainThread] Collector failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/diamond/utils/scheduler.py", line 73, in collector_process
    collector._run()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/diamond/collector.py", line 472, in _run
    self.collect()
  File "/usr/share/diamond/collectors/memory_docker/memory_docker.py", line 34, in collect
    for c in docker.Client().containers(all=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 70, in containers
    res = self._result(self._get(u, params=params), True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 120, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 487, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 453, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[2016-09-11 08:07:33,719] [MainThread] Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/diamond/collectors/docker_collector/docker_collector.py", line 67, in collect
    client = docker.Client(version='auto')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 81, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 105, in _retrieve_server_version
"diamond.log.2016-09-11" [readonly] 131088L, 9082758C                                                                         1,1           Top
```

Please guide me on how I can investigate further.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Does this happend with the latest version from this github? https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond
Looks like you are using a lib that you don't have - this one:https://github.com/avalente/appmetrics